# Request Timed Out (Wire connection)

Tags: ping, router

I am having problem pinging my next router which is in the garage (Fiber Connection)

my router with ip 192.168.1.1

```
Pinging 192.168.1.1 with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 192.168.1.1: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.1.1: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.1.1: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.1.1: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.1.1: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.1.1: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.1.1: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.1.1: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.1.1: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.1.1: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.1.1: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.1.1: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.1.1: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=64
```

The problem is with the next hop which is my next gateway that the ISP installed

```
Pinging 79.134.128.1 with 32 bytes of data:
Request timed out.
Reply from 79.134.128.1: bytes=32 time=6ms TTL=252
Reply from 79.134.128.1: bytes=32 time=2ms TTL=252
Reply from 79.134.128.1: bytes=32 time=5ms TTL=252
Reply from 79.134.128.1: bytes=32 time=4ms TTL=252
Request timed out.
Request timed out.
Reply from 79.134.128.1: bytes=32 time=4ms TTL=252
Reply from 79.134.128.1: bytes=32 time=10ms TTL=252
Reply from 79.134.128.1: bytes=32 time=7ms TTL=252
Request timed out.
Request timed out.
Reply from 79.134.128.1: bytes=32 time=3ms TTL=252
Reply from 79.134.128.1: bytes=32 time=5ms TTL=252
Reply from 79.134.128.1: bytes=32 time=5ms TTL=252
Request timed out.
Reply from 79.134.128.1: bytes=32 time=4ms TTL=252
Reply from 79.134.128.1: bytes=32 time=6ms TTL=252
Reply from 79.134.128.1: bytes=32 time=2ms TTL=252
Reply from 79.134.128.1: bytes=32 time=3ms TTL=252
Reply from 79.134.128.1: bytes=32 time=5ms TTL=252
Reply from 79.134.128.1: bytes=32 time=4ms TTL=252
Request timed out.
Reply from 79.134.128.1: bytes=32 time=8ms TTL=252
Reply from 79.134.128.1: bytes=32 time=2ms TTL=252
Reply from 79.134.128.1: bytes=32 time=7ms TTL=252
Reply from 79.134.128.1: bytes=32 time=6ms TTL=252
Request timed out.
Reply from 79.134.128.1: bytes=32 time=5ms TTL=252
Request timed out.
```

i m having internet loss as well like pinging yahoo.com

i tried using my laptop to ping the router but the same problem occurs

what could be the issue?

Comment: Ok it turns out to be the router is defective. I have unplugged it from power then plugged it again now it worked fine so far. I would say do not use this cheap shit TP-Link router avoid it at all cost. I am using NetGear now.